# XSLT - Conditional Formatting on Date Column

Tags: xslt, formatting

Is it possible to apply conditional formatting to a date column? I'm trying to set the columns background to red if the date has passed using the following

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space($thisNode/@Completion_x0020_Date) >= 'Today'" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1">background-color: #71B84F;</xsl:if>
```

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this from a [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/02/25/filtering-and-formatting-with-date-values.aspx) about filtering and formatting with Date Values.  At this point, the main problem is around the formatting of the comparison.  This is xml so when the parser sees ">', it views as the closing bracket and not as a comparison.  You need to encode this as

```
"&gt;="
```

for the comparison to be recognized.

```
<xsl:if test="number(translate(substringbefore
(@Modified_Recently$Modified_Recently_ISO,'T'), '-',''))
&gt;= number(translate(substring-before($Today,'T'),'-',''))">
background-color: #00FF00;
</xsl:if>
```